# Spring Roo DBRE SQL Azure connection

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-sql-database, roo

Has anybody successfully reverse engineered a SQL Azure database using Spring Roo ?

I am using the JDBC driver and just get a message of 'Connection Required' whenever I try to run any of the 'database instropect' commands from Roo console.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Are you able to run any command via JDBC (i.e. non-Roo ones) to confirm that the connection string settings are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. In case it helps anyone, you need to create an OSGi wrapper for Microsoft's JDBC driver. I installed the Azure SDK, which includes this file, and made a note of the path to it.

```
addon create wrapper --topLevelPackage com.sqlserver.roo.JDBC --groupId com.microsoft.sqlserver --     artifactId sqljdbc4 --version 4.0 --vendorName Microsoft --licenseUrl http://www.microsoft.com

osgi install --url file:///C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/spring-workspace/osgi/target/com.sqlserver.roo.jdbc.sqljdbc4-4.0.0001.jar

database reverse engineer --schema dbo
```

Credit: https://nidget.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-osgify-an-oracle-jdbc-driver-with-spring-roo/